# Почему при запуске ноутбука меня выкидывает в boot menu?

Tags: bios

После сброса bios до дефолтных настроек.
Ноутбук долго загружается и высвечивает вот это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
после чего меня выкидывает в boot menu.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я уже менял порядок загрузки в bios на приоритетный hard disk

Но это не помогло в чем причина и как это исправить?

Все настройки моего bios
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй изменить тип загрузки  (UEFI vs Legacy)

Comment: попробуй найти “LAN Boot” и переключить в режим Disable  Вместо “LAN Boot” может быть “PXE Boot” и т. п.

Comment: @Даниил Кажется в моем bios нет таких настроек